# Enable user to send and receive email through AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

My knowledge of AWS is very basic and I am studying to enable a user to send and receive email using SES.

The user is created in IAM and with SES permission enabled.

[image]

The domain is already registered and working on AWS.

[image]

Do I need to create a email inside SMTP configuration or is there a option to create email on IAM user profile?

[image]

Comment: You can use the AWS API, you do not need to use SMTP. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendEmail.html

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to read the Doc first Because they clearly explained how it works. There are 2 main methods to send an email using SES.

**1. SES Rest APIs**

It's a REST API service for SES. You can send emails by calling API as an HTTP Request. Visit the below link for more info.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-api.html

**2. SMTP**

It's a traditional way. But if you want to access the SMTP server, You need to create SMTP credentials first. These credentials are unique to regions. If you are sending emails from multiple regions, You need to create a set of credentials for each.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html

**Receiving Emails**

SES allows you to receive emails too. But this feature only available in certain regions. You can access received emails via the following ways without SMTP,

- Deliver incoming emails to the S3 bucket
- Publish to SNS topic
- Send to Amazon WorkMail

For more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email.html

Comment: Thanks @BadPiggie.. I checked the document, when I verify new email address puttins external email, like gmail, and send email for test, it works.. But when I set email using my domain, I have to verify, but I cannot read.. Is there any way to read email instead of using SMTP software, like Outlook?

Comment: So you want to receive & read emails via SES?

Comment: So you want to receive & read emails via SES? --> yes

Comment: I updated the answer with receiving methods. Have a look.